# Screen rendering issue after upgrade from 5.8.0-48 to -49 and -50

Tags: graphics, display

My system has integrated graphics, Intel i5 chip. After upgrading from 5.8.0.48-generic to -49, after reboot, I noted browser screen does not update correctly. Missing images and text, flickering. I opened a terminal to check the kernel version installed (uname -a) and noticed the terminal also has same problem, flickering and characters appearing and disappearing.

So I booted the previous kernel, 48. and everything was fine, no problem with screen update. Today, I checked for update and there was 5.8.0-50 available part of the update. After update, booted with default (5.8.0-50-generic) and noticed the same screen issue, but not as bad as the previous kernel, -49.
Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: is it similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331116/pc-has-started-breaking-and-become-very-unstable ?