# Screen blinking in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: desktop-environments, 20.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.10 but I'm facing a problem.

When I open any software like Google Chrome, Visual Studio Code or any other system app the screen starts blinking.

When I had Ubuntu 20.04 there was no problem.

This started happening when I upgraded to 20.10. I'm using GNOME Desktop.

I'm not able to use Ubuntu 20.10 properly. Refer these screenshots:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Video Clip :

https://mrunkn.000webhostapp.com/Ubuntu/screen1.webm

you can see the blinking desktop icons

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: How do you see screen blinking in a still picture?

Comment: look at tabs in chrome in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/YngtF.jpg

Comment: Any improvement if you choose the light theme? In your **Displays** settings panel, what choices do you see for **Refresh rate**? Show me `uname -r`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema   uname -r  showing  ->  5.8.0-50-generic

Comment: @heynnema I have added video clip of this problem you can see -> https://mrunkn.000webhostapp.com/Ubuntu/screen1.webm  plz help me to resolve this

Comment: @heynnema  my **Refresh Rate** is  **59.789539337158203**  I got this in .config/monitors.xml  file

Comment: For Refresh Rate, look at the **Displays** settings panel, and tell me the choices you see there. Look at `ls -al /boot` and see if you find the 5.8.0-48 kernel. If so, boot to GRUB, Advanced Options, and choose 5.8.0-48. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema  i've selected 5.8.0-48 now what i should do next..?

Comment: @heynnema i think problem is solved thank you so much ..

Comment: You stay running on -48 until they release a -51 or newer kernel. Please see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331116/pc-started-having-screen-glitches-after-update.