# UI Glitches Solution Help

Tags: 22.04, gui

I'm having some issues with some strange graphical glitches in Ubuntu. The problem is outlined pretty clearly at this link, and the top answer seems to fix it from the upvotes, but I can’t seem to get it to work.
[PC started having screen glitches after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331116/pc-started-having-screen-glitches-after-update)
The gif in the above question shows a sort of jumping back and forth, and this is something I'm experiencing across all applications. Even when typing, sometimes it will look like it deleted the last word or two and jump back. Other times it will rapidly scroll a few pixels up and down. I'm very confused how this would happen in the first place. Unfortunately it's been making the environment unworkable.
It suggests using the -48 kernel, which should be accessible from the GRUB menu. I believe Update #1 might be referring to some people (like me) not seeing the option for that at startup. It tells you to use Synaptic to get some files. I downloaded Synaptic and couldn't find those. I guess my question here is has anybody dealt with this issue before that could help with some guidance? I realize this answer was from two years ago

Comment: As you have a newer Ubuntu release you can assume that your default kernel is not the faulty kernel mentioned in the linked question and the named older kernel versions are not relevant here. Please [edit] your question and add details about your graphics card and the driver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, which version of Ubuntu are you running and what hardware do you have?

The general rule of thumb is that most hardware issues/glitches are resolved with newer kernels, so it is usually a good idea to install the newest kernel available for your Ubuntu release, or even an OEM kernel.

The post that you have found is about Ubuntu 20.04. Are you still using 20.04? You can check you Ubuntu version by running this command in the terminal:

```
lsb_release -a
```